# Dados do formulário

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário já formatado em CSS e HTML. Como faço para receber os dados informados no formulário, após preenchimento?

Não compreendo muito sobre PHP.

```
<form class="w3-container" id="contato">
  <p>
  <label><b>Nome</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="nome"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>Sobrenome</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="empresa"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>E-mail</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="email"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>Telefone</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="telefone"</p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-center w3-gray" style="margin-left:270px">
</form>
```

Utilizo o atributo `method` em `form`? Como enviar os dados informados pra um endereço específico?

Comment: Precisa compreender o mínimo em php... No seu form vc tem um `method` e um `action` ,  então para onde apontar o `action` vc captura o valor pelas variáveis `$_POST['name_do_campo'] ou $_GET['name_do_campo']` dependendo do método que usa... http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php Considere fazer um [tour] e edite sua questão para receber uma resposta e evitar o fechamento desta,,,

Comment: Dá mais uma olhada aqui :https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve coloque seu código html...

Comment: O que você quer é enviar os dados do formulário para um email?

Comment: Exato! É exatamente o que eu preciso.

Comment: Leonardo, agora vendo os comentários finais, enviar para o email já um pouco mais avançado, mas não muito, o fato é que dessa forma me parece estar pulando etapas, aqui o pessoal gosta de ajudar, mas creio que não entendeu o funcionamento do site direito, da forma que está sua pergunta se torna ampla e possivelmente será fechada... Entenda como uma crítica construtiva, não pule etapas, aqui você conseguirá respostas para todas suas dúvidas, desde que sua pergunta esteja dentro dos moldes ... Leia [help] com calma, e divida seus problemas em pequenas partes... Boa Sorte !

Answer (score 0):

Para receber os dados no form, o básico é assim:

Na tag `form` você tem 2 atributos relevantes nesse cenário. o `method` e o `action`.

Por padrão na ausência do `action` ele irá retornar a ação na mesma página, caso seu `form` esteja salvo em uma página `.html`, você não conseguira receber os dados pelo `php` na mesma página, tornando necessário definir um `action` que apontara para a página que receberá esses dados, .ex:

```
<form action="recebe_dodos.php">
```

O outro atributo `method`, especifica o método da requisição, que por padrão é `$_GET`.

```
<form method="GET" action="recebe_dados.php">
```

Existe um terceiro atributo relevante, o `name`. Ele identifica o nome do campo.

```
<input name="dado_nome"/>
```

O valor deste `name` é o que será usado para receber o dado, ex:

```
<form class="w3-container" id="contato" method="GET" action="recebe_dados.php">
  <p>
      <label><b>Nome</b></label>
      <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="nome" name="dado_nome"/>
      <input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-center w3-gray" style="margin-left:270px"/>

  </p>
</form>
```

recebe_dados.php

```
<?php
$nome = $_GET['dado_nome'];//pegando o valor do input com o name 'dado_nome' e atribuindo a variável $nome;
echo $nome;// A saída é nome digitado.
?>
```

Em resumo é isso...

Comment: Obrigado! Vou tentar. Procurei inclusive no W3 Schools, yahoo answers e tudo o mais. Meu problema maior não está sendo declarar os inputs... Toda vez que clico enviar no meu html offline, ele abre a página .php. Vou utilizar um free webhost pra ver se consigo por em prática, parte por parte e assim refinar o que precisa ser refinado! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Após receber os dados do form, para enviar a um e-mail... Este e-mail tem que ser um do mesmo webhost ou pode ser qualquer um?

Comment: Tamo aqui para isso...  Para fazer esses teste se só precisa configurar um  Apache... Daí se manda até com gmail... Depois que fizer os testes, considere avaliar minha resposta... gL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Repare que cada input foi dado um `name`, **modifiquei seu código**

```
<form class="w3-container" id="contato" method="post">
  <p>
  <label><b>Nome</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>Sobrenome</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="empresa" name="empresa"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>E-mail</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
  <p>
  <label><b>Telefone</b></label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-animate-input" type="text" id="telefone"></p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-center w3-gray" name="btn-form" style="margin-left:270px">
</form>
```

Agora vamos recuperar os dados passado no `form` veja que dei um `name` para cada input e pro seu `submit` (botão) veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
//Se existir o clicki no botão
if (isset($_POST['btn-form'])) {
 //Váriavel nome recebe input POST nome
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];

 //Validando o formulário
 if (empty($nome)) {
   echo "Preencha seu nome";
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você poderá usar no php `$_GET['nomedoinputnamehtml'];` caso o seu form method seja GET  ou `$_POST['nomedoinputnamehtml'];` caso o seu form method seja POST.

Exemplo HTML:

`<form method="POST" action="meuphp.php">
   <input name="email">
 </form>`

Exemplo meuphp.php:

`<?php
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   echo $email;
 ?>`

Acho que é isso, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Assim eu conseguiria enviar para um endereço de e-mail específico? Ou apenas armazenar num banco de dados, @Nathan Macedo?

Comment: Olha seu exemplo tem uma série de erros, considere revê-lo para não ser negativado.

Comment: @LeonardoMatiazzo este exemplo é só um trecho básico que você precisará fazer ajustes a sua necessidade. No caso você queira fazer uma conexão com um banco de dados ou até mesmo enviar via e-mail. Considero interessante você procurar na documentação do PHP como se faz a conexão com o banco de sua preferência indico PDO e no caso você queira enviar por e-mail por usar a função mail do php ou uma classe já existente e bem famosa como a PHPMailer. Segue abaixo alguns links: 
-http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php
-https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: @MagicHat  
Considere me apresentar o erro para que eu possa aprender também !

Comment: Você fez o teste do seu código ? Ou só escreveu e pensou: "Isso está correto ! Vou postar." ?

Comment: @MagicHat na verdade eu só quis dar as diretrizes pra ele referente a dúvida dele. Não somente digitar o código por ele. Mas se eu pegar aquele código eu provavelmente faria ele funcionar colocando somente um botão submit e colocando a estrutura html padrão no exemplo do html.

Comment: Cara não leve a mal, eu pergunto dessa forma as vezes que é para a pessoa refletir, nem sei se é correto,mas assim que eu faço e nem foi eu quem negativou, raramente o faço, deveria fazer mais, o fato é que : a 1º tag de abertura do form não está fechada, idem a do input, e você colocou o echo na variável com aspas simples... São uma série de erros que eu apenas notei e como vc através do meu questionamento quis dar-lhe diretrizes para você rever seu código, mas nem sequer você considerou... Entenda como uma crítica construtiva...

Comment: Sim, obrigado .